# JavaScript window.location.href not working in localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my website.
When there is "333" in the input box (id textbox_text) website is supposed to redirect to the specified url, but instead nothing happens.
Where is the problem?

```
    <script>
            function IsEmpty()
            {
            if(document.forms['frm'].textbox_text.value == "333")
             {
                window.location.href="martyna-lesniak.html";
            }
            else 
            {
                alert("Nieprawidłowe hasło!");
            }
        }
    </script>
    <div class="container">
        <form name="frm">
            <input type="password" name="password1" class="password-input" id="textbox_text" placeholder="Wpisz hasło">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return IsEmpty();" value="Wysyłaj" class="button-input" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use window.location.replace(url). Href only works on click

Comment: Still nothing :/ Page just refreshes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to `return false;` after your call to `window.location.href="martyna-lesniak.html";`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the HTML that you need to refer in other folder that the actual html you need to put the path of the resource (html) the other thing is in the conditional you can put === to have a literal equal object

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
        function IsEmpty()
        {
        if(document.forms['frm'].textbox_text.value == "333")
         {

            window.location.href="martyna-lesniak.html";
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            alert("Nieprawidłowe hasło!");
        }
    }
</script>
<div class="container">
    <form name="frm">
        <input type="password" name="password1" class="password-input" id="textbox_text" placeholder="Wpisz hasło">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return IsEmpty();" value="Wysyłaj" class="button-input" />
    </form>
</div>
```