Redirect to another page after submitting form ASP NET
I want to redirect user to another page after submitting form. I have  Create page where user enter data and Learning with view data.
Create View
@model Deck

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="~/js/script.js">
    </script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous" asp-append-version="true">    
</head>

<body>

<main class="main">
  <div class="container">
        <div class="new-module d-flex justify-content-between mt-5">
            <h1>Create new module</h1>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Cards" asp-action="learning" type="submit">Создать</a>
        </div>

        <div class="card mt-5 p-2 pb-3">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <input class="form-control w-100" placeholder="Enter a name">
        </div>
        <form asp-controller="Cards" asp-action="Create" method="post" class="cards">
            <div class="card mt-6" id="card">
                <div class="header d-flex justify-content-between p-3">
                    <h4 class="card-counter">1</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body row">
                    <div class="term col">
                        <h3>Term</h3>
                        <input class="form-control w-100" name = "term" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="definition col">
                        <h3>Definition </h3>
                        <input class="form-control w-100" name = "definition"  >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Create" id="create-cards" class="btn btn-primary mt-2"/>
        </form>
        <button class="new-card w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-4 mt-s rounded-2" style="height: 5rem"  type="button">
            <h3>+ Add card</h3>
        </button>
  </div>

</main>
</body>

</html>

script.js
var currentCardNumber = 1;

function addCard() {

    currentCardNumber++;
    let newCardHTML = `
                    <div class="header d-flex justify-content-between p-3">
                        <h4 class="card-counter">${currentCardNumber}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body row">
                        <div class="term col">
                            <h3>Term</h3>
                            <input class="form-control w-100" name = "term" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="definition col">
                            <h3>Definition </h3>
                            <input class="form-control w-100" name="definition" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div> `;
    let newCard = document.createElement('div');
    newCard.classList.add('card');
    newCard.classList.add('mt-3');
    newCard.innerHTML = newCardHTML;

    let addNewCard = document.querySelector('.cards');
    let referenceNode = document.getElementById('create-cards');
    addNewCard.insertBefore(newCard, referenceNode);

}
function saveCardDataToServer() {
    let cards = [];
    document.querySelectorAll('.cards > .card   ').forEach((card) => {

        let termInput = card.querySelector('input[name="term"]');
        let definitionInput = card.querySelector('input[name="definition"]');

        if (termInput && definitionInput) {
            let term = termInput.value.trim();
            let definition = definitionInput.value.trim();
            cards.push({
                Term: term,
                Definition: definition
            });
        }
        else {
            console.error("Input elements not found in card:", card);
        }
    })

    fetch('/Cards/Create/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({Cards: cards})
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data => {
            if (data.success) {
                console.log("Data successfully saved: ", data);
                window.location.href = "/Cards/Learning";
            } else {
                console.error("Error saving card: ", data.message);
            }
        }))
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let newCard = document.querySelector('.new-card');
  newCard.addEventListener('click', function() {
    addCard();
  });
  document.querySelector('form.cards').addEventListener('submit', function() {
    saveCardDataToServer();
  });
});

Controller
public class CardsController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Learning()
    {
        var cards = CardsRepository.GetCards();
        return View(cards);
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Cards/Create/")]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Deck deck)

    {
        if (deck != null && deck.Cards != null)
        {
            foreach (var card in deck.Cards)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(card.Term) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(card.Definition))
                {
                    CardsRepository.AddCard(card);
                }
            }
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Card saved successfully " });
        }
        return Json(new {
            success = false, message = "Invalid data provided"
        });
    }

}

Models
public class Deck
{
    public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }

    public Deck()
    {
        Cards = new List<Card>();
    }
}

public class Card
{
    public int CardId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Term { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Definition { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

I tried <input type="submit" value="Создать" id="create-cards" class="btn btn-primary mt-2" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Learning")'"/> in view and document.getElementById('create-cards').addEventListener('click',function (){ window.location.href = "/Create/Learning"; }); in js, it's useless.
Strange thing when I submit form with breakpoint on the fetch in debugger all working correctly

Add return false; after your call to window.location.href;
Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61434833/11993452
Or you can redirect from controller method by
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Learning));

Added return false; and redirect from controller method by return RedirectToAction(nameof(Learning)); doesn't help. However, if I added return false; and clicked the button and came back to the first page and clicked the button again it works correctly

try removing the form tag and change this code document.querySelector('form.cards').addEventListener('submit', function() {
saveCardDataToServer();
}); cause it uses "form.card". You can use id to find element here to add eventlistner.

In your code on submitting there is form submit going on and submit event on javascript. Try to focus on any one of them. Remove any one of them and try like the previous comment.

Another thing don't add return false; when you use return RedirectToAction(nameof(Learning)); and make sure the execution reaches the controller onsubmit
